# Azure SCOPE_INDENTITY() DBPARM

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, scope-identity

when using SQL Server with the Native Client, I get funny results if in the DBParm I do **not** specify the:

```
TrimSpaces=1,RecheckRows=1,Identity='SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I am thinking jumping into Azure. Will these DBParms be recognized by Azure?

Also, can I include

```
Expect100Continue = false,ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false
```

in my connection string using the SQL Native Client?

Thank you